# selecting with a column being one of two possible values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called "people" with a column named "name". I would like to select all rows where the name is "bob" or "john". I have tried the following and many variants of it, none of which work. How can I do this correctly?

```
select * from people where name is bob or john;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To compare a column with a value you need to use `=` not `IS`

```
select * 
from people 
where name = 'bob' 
  or name = 'john';
```

Alternatively you can use the IN operator.

```
select * 
from people 
where name IN ('bob','john');
```

Note that string comparison is case-sensitive in SQL. So the above will not return rows where the name is `Bob` or `John`

Comment: No it is usually non-case-sensitive.

Comment: @SalmanA: In "SQL" (the query language) the comparison **is** case-sensitive some DBMS products have different defaults though. But in PostgreSQL (and many other DBMS products) it is most definitely case-sensitive